# Cleaning up first part of serial read string

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am currently reading data coming in continuously from an i2c sensor connected to an Arduino and capturing the data successfully. The sensor is getting 4 different X, Y values and then sends them via Serial.Print in the format of:

X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4 (Where X1 - X4 and Y1 - Y4 are values that range between 0-1023 i.e., 1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023) which is then followed up with a Serial.println("") command. This whole process is repeated continuously until turned off.

My issue right now is that the first part of the string that comes through has data at the front end of it that is completely unusable and then it normalizes to the data that I can read and use. Serial monitor results: 
[image]

Continues like this until stopped.

I'm trying to read this from a Visual Studios project and that first set of data is really inhibiting my ability to move forward as I want to put the values into an array. Visual studios gets hung up on the serial read -> array because of the strange characters. Any help would be appreciated.

Arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
int IRsensorAddress = 0xB0;
//int IRsensorAddress = 0x58;

int slaveAddress;
int ledPin = 13;
boolean ledState = false;
byte data_buf[16];
int i;
int Ix[4];
int Iy[4];
int s;
byte test = 1023.5f;

void Write_2bytes(byte d1, byte d2)
  {
      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(d1); Wire.write(d2);
      Wire.endTransmission();
  }


void setup()
{
      slaveAddress = IRsensorAddress >> 1; // This results in 0x21 as the address to pass to TWI
      Serial.begin(19200);
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Set the LED pin as output
      Wire.begin();

      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(0x30); Wire.write(0x01);
      Wire.endTransmission(); delay(10);

      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(0x00); Wire.write(0x00);Wire.write(0x00); Wire.write(0x00);Wire.write(0x00); Wire.write(0x00);Wire.write(0x00); Wire.write(0x09);
      Wire.endTransmission(); delay(10);

      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(0x07); Wire.write(0x00);Wire.write(0x41);
      Wire.endTransmission(); delay(10);

      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(0x1A); Wire.write(0x40);Wire.write(0x00);
      Wire.endTransmission(); delay(10);

      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(0x33); Wire.write(0x03);
      Wire.endTransmission(); delay(10);

      Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
      Wire.write(0x30); Wire.write(0x08);
      Wire.endTransmission(); delay(10);
      delay(100);
      /* IR sensor initialize
      Write_2bytes(0x30,0x01); delay(10);
      Write_2bytes(0x30,0x08); delay(10);
      Write_2bytes(0x06,0x90); delay(10);
      Write_2bytes(0x08,0xC0); delay(10);
      Write_2bytes(0x1A,0x40); delay(10);
      Write_2bytes(0x33,0x33); delay(10);
      delay(100);
      */
}    
void loop()
    {
        ledState = !ledState;
        if (ledState) { digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH); } else { digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW); }

        //IR sensor read
        Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
        Wire.write(0x36);
        Wire.endTransmission();
        Wire.requestFrom(slaveAddress, 16); // Request the 2 byte heading (MSB comes first)

        for (i=0;i<16;i++) { data_buf[i]=0; }
        i=0;

        while(Wire.available() && i < 16) {
            data_buf[i] = Wire.read();
            i++;
        }

        Ix[0] = data_buf[1];
        Iy[0] = data_buf[2];
        s = data_buf[3];
        //Ix[0] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
        Ix[0] = data_buf[1] | ((data_buf[3] >> 4) & 0x03) << 8;
        Iy[0] = data_buf[2] | ((data_buf[3] >> 6) & 0x03) << 8;
        //Ix[0] = Ix[0] / test;

        Ix[1] = data_buf[4];
        Iy[1] = data_buf[5];
        s = data_buf[6];
        Ix[1] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
        Iy[1] += (s & 0xC0) <<2;

        Ix[2] = data_buf[7];
        Iy[2] = data_buf[8];
        s = data_buf[9];
        Ix[2] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
        Iy[2] += (s & 0xC0) <<2;

        Ix[3] = data_buf[10];
        Iy[3] = data_buf[11];
        s = data_buf[12];
        Ix[3] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
        Iy[3] += (s & 0xC0) <<2;

        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if (Ix[i] < 1000)
                Serial.print("");
            if (Ix[i] < 100)
                Serial.print("");
            if (Ix[i] < 10)
                Serial.print("");
            Serial.print( int(Ix[i]) );
            Serial.print(",");
            if (Iy[i] < 1000)
                Serial.print("");
            if (Iy[i] < 100)
                Serial.print("");
            if (Iy[i] < 10)
                Serial.print("");
            Serial.print( int(Iy[i]) );
            if (i<3)
                Serial.print(",");
        }

        //Serial.print(",");
        Serial.println("");
        delay(15);
    }
```

I  can also provide the visual studios code if this problem can be fixed from within that C# project.

Comment: Are you connecting/disconnecting the serial interface during transmission. Can you post the code in the `setup()` function that initializes the serial interface.

Comment: @StefanBossbaly I have updated the Arduino code to include the entire sketch

Comment: Wherever the noise is coming from (perhaps it's the receiver UART starts off at a different default baud rate then your receiver program changes it to the required speed and there is some garbage still in the input buffer?) your receiver code needs to discard data until it sees some good data. One way of doing it might be to look for the carriage return, then check that the received string has eight numbers separated by commas - if not throw it away and start again looking for carriage return. And for robustness allow this process to repeat if the receiver loses sync.

Comment: @barny I thought it might be a baud rate issue. I've been looking for templates on how to discard based on carriage return or not and how to check if the string length validation as well. I've found plenty of examples in Java but I'm not the best with C#